# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError dynamoDB android timeoffset

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This is the error I'm getting when I try to connect to my database

```
Thread task2 = new Thread(()->{
    this.dbTable = Table.loadTable(dbClient2,"USERS");
});task2.start();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
    Process: com.example.storybook, PID: 31285
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No instance field timeOffset of type I in class Lcom/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient' appears in /data/app/~~)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:5151)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1526)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.document.Table.loadTableDescription(Table.java:124)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.document.Table.loadTable(Table.java:110)
        at com.example.storybook.cloud.AWS.dynamodb.lambda$Initialize$1$dynamodb(dynamodb.java:73)
        at com.example.storybook.cloud.AWS.-$$Lambda$dynamodb$HsXHij-2LiApdW7ep5CzVtBmPNg.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out you need to be using compatible versions of the AWS ddb library and the AWS core library to make sure you can always throw a plus at the end of the include in your graddle file